# Unable to get response response from Postman after passing JSON data with POST request

Tags: node.js, postman

I am making a POST request from Postman with JSON data having email and password but when I tried to show that in Postman's response window it's showing nothing.

It seems that the POST request is not sending the JSON data with a request or I might be something wrong while accessing the request data.

Here is my code:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();

    const database = {
      users: [
        {
          id: "1234",
          name: "john",
          email: "john@gmail.com",
          password: "john",
          entries: 0,
          joined: new Date()
        },
        {
          id: "123",
          name: "sally",
          email: "sally@gmail.com",
          password: "sally",
          entries: 0,
          joined: new Date()
        }
      ]
    };

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("This is working Get");
    });

    app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
      res.json(req.body);
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Server Started at port number 3000");
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with express, You need 'body-parser' module for post request to work,

```
 const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.raw());
    const database = {
      users: [
        {
          id: "1234",
          name: "john",
          email: "john@gmail.com",
          password: "john",
          entries: 0,
          joined: new Date()
        },
        {
          id: "123",
          name: "sally",
          email: "sally@gmail.com",
          password: "sally",
          entries: 0,
          joined: new Date()
        }
      ]
    };

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("This is working Get");
    });

    app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
      res.json(req.body);
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Server Started at port number 3000");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 :** 
    If you are making request using `raw(application/json)` then you need to install below npm that will parse you request data,

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Plesae go throgh the below link for more info :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

**Step 2 :**  You need to add below line in your server file

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

**Step 3 :** Once you integrate the `bodyParser` you can access your request data using `req.body`

Here is you code with solution :

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

const database = {
    users: [{
            id: "1234",
            name: "john",
            email: "john@gmail.com",
            password: "john",
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        },
        {
            id: "123",
            name: "sally",
            email: "sally@gmail.com",
            password: "sally",
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    ]
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Server has been started");
});
```